# Want to have my textarea format it's readonly text like html

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, textarea

I have a read-only textarea that I display which acts as my old blog posts (which are editable in a field below it) and I'd like to be able to format it's contents somewhat.  Ideally, I'd like it to look like HTML code, but at the very least, I'd like when the entered a URL, I'd like to display it as a href link.

Are there any best practices for this?  Or do I have to process each and look for and format the items I want?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason it is a `textarea` and not just a `div` or something?

Comment: ok - that seems obvious, and I'll look at that.  I'm formatting it in a list, and I wanted it to look the same as the editable textarea I had below it, but now that you suggest that, I'll try that.  Thanks.

Comment: well - the reason I'm using the textarea is because I want to display the newlines that are entered in the field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a simple div (or paragraph element, or whatever) with the `white-space: pre` CSS property to display newlines.

```
#div-mimicking-textarea { white-space: pre; }
```

It is not possible to have an anchor element within a textarea.

Comment: OK.  That is helpful - I wasn't aware of that CSS property.  Thank you.